# Как в python подключить pgfoundry?

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm

Народ, в общем, появилась необходимость сделать следующее: скриптом python подключитья к pg, получить данные и записать их на веб-сервере как date.php.

Скачал www.jetbrains.com/pycharm   /, скачал python.projects.pgfoundry.org, но что делать дальше? Я даже импортировать забыл как. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

**UPD**

Как в python подключить pgfoundry?

Comment: @anunak, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий за участников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/02/python-postgres.html